# SQL Percentage elegance

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

I am just starting to get familiar with SQL and I find the language easy enough but also quite messy at times. For example take this statement

```
SELECT transaction.ID, 
       dt,
       bundles.package_name as "Package Name",
       amount_usd, 
       unit_sales, 
CASE 
    WHEN sum(amount_usd) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE round(amount_usd*100/ (SELECT sum(amount_usd) FROM transaction 
          WHERE (transaction.code = 'AA')
           AND (transaction.country_code = 'US')
           AND (dt BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-04')),2)
END as percentage

FROM transaction 
  JOIN bundles
   ON transaction.package_id= cast(bundles.id as INT)

WHERE (transaction.code = 'AA')
AND (transaction.country_code = 'US')
AND (dt BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-04')

GROUP BY transaction.ID, dt, "Package Name"
ORDER BY transaction.ID
limit 1000
```

I found a little bit of a waste to have to repeat the SELECT plus FROM just to calculate the percentage properly. Is there a more elegant solution to avoid such things?

---

Here is how I have fixed it.

If you want the percentage over the total sum you don't need necessarily to nest

```
SELECT t.ID, dt, b.package_name as "Package Name",
       SUM(amount_usd) as amount_usd, SUM(unit_sales) as unit_sales, 
       SUM(amount_usd) * 1.0 / SUM(amount_usd) OVER () as ratio
FROM transaction t JOIN
     bundles b
     ON t.package_id = cast(b.id as INT)
WHERE (t.code = 'AA') AND
      (t.country_code = 'US') AND
      (dt BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-04')
GROUP BY t.ID, dt, "Package Name"
ORDER BY t.ID
LIMIT 1000;
```

If you want the ratio of revenue over the total per day you do

```
SELECT t.ID, dt, b.package_name as "Package Name",
       SUM(amount_usd) as amount_usd, SUM(unit_sales) as unit_sales, 
       SUM(amount_usd) * 1.0 / SUM(amount_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) as ratio
FROM transaction t JOIN
     bundles b
     ON t.package_id = cast(b.id as INT)
WHERE (t.code = 'AA') AND
      (t.country_code = 'US') AND
      (dt BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-04')
GROUP BY t.ID, dt, "Package Name"
ORDER BY t.ID
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added

Answer (score 0):

Most dialects of SQL support the ANSI standard window functions.  In addition, formatting is often handled at the application later.

So, this would typically be written as:

```
SELECT t.ID, dt, b.package_name as "Package Name",
       SUM(amount_usd) as amount_usd, SUM(unit_sales) as unit_sales, 
       SUM(amount_usd) * 1.0 / NULLIF(SUM(SUM(amount_usd)) OVER ()) as ratio
FROM transaction t JOIN
     bundles b
     ON t.package_id = cast(b.id as INT)
WHERE (t.code = 'AA') AND
      (t.country_code = 'US') AND
      (dt BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-04')
GROUP BY t.ID, dt, "Package Name"
ORDER BY t.ID
LIMIT 1000;
```

Other issues in your query:

- Qualify all column names when a query has more than one table.
- Use table abbreviations as table aliases -- much easier to write and read.
- The `JOIN` keys on different tables should be the same type.  In fact, they should be declared as proper foreign key relationships.
- You were missing some aggregation functions in your `SELECT`.  Be sure the only unaggregated columns are the `GROUP BY` keys.

If your database vendor doesn't support ANSI standard functionality, that is something you should take up with them.

Comment: I assume you meant "*when a **query** has more than one table*" not "*when a table has more than one table*"

Comment: I get "aggregate function calls cannot be nested"

Comment: @PasqualeSada . . . It is valid ANSI standard SQL.  If you have a question about a particular database, you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @PasqualeSada . . . Here is a simple rextester that shows that the syntax works:  http://rextester.com/YQMV53134.

Comment: I will check with the vendor. I have noticed that now the ratio is the amount_usd/total amount_usd but I need a ratio per day (amount_usd sold that day per package divided total amount sold in that day) .